# How to extract weights of network?

Tags: caffe, extract

I want to extract the weights of an optimized network with `python`. I have the `.caffemodel` file and I've obtained `net.params` which gives me the parameters of the whole network. The problem is when I am calling it for the for example the first layer, i.e. `net.params['ip2']` it gives me:

```
<caffe._caffe.BlobVec object at 0x7f1cb03c8fa0>
```

How I can get the matrix of the weights, instead of the pointer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to read the network using the .prototxt file and the .caffemodel file.

```
net = caffe.Net('path/to/conv.prototxt', 'path/to/conv.caffemodel', caffe.TEST)
W = net.params['con_1'][0].data[...]
b = net.params['con_1'][1].data[...]
```

Have a look at this [link](http://christopher5106.github.io/deep/learning/2015/09/04/Deep-learning-tutorial-on-Caffe-Technology.html) and this [link](https://gist.github.com/FranciscoCanas/844aab52fcff6b1c652a) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I got it,
it can be obtained with `weights2 = net.params['ip2'][0].data`

Comment: Just be aware that `params['ip2'][0]` will give you the weight and `params['ip2'][1]` will give you the bias term (if your model has a bias term).